# how to use curl command in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

curl –i -u account_id:api_key "https://xecdapi.xe.com/v1/account_info/"

i want to use the above curl command in angularjs. I tried by including header but i didn't get any result.thanks in advance strong text
i want to use the above curl command in angularjs. I tried by including header but i didn't get any result.thanks in advance strong text
i want to use the above curl command in angularjs. I tried by including header but i didn't get any result.thanks in advance strong text

Comment: i believe you are looking for ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You should use http service from angular to send requests. [First article from google](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/using-oauth-2-0-service-ionicframework/)

```
 $http.get('https://xecdapi.xe.com/v1/account_info/', {
        headers: {"Authorization": "Basic account_id:api_key"})
        .success(function(response){
        console.log(response)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl and Wget - these are system level tokens. You cannot use these inside Angular environment.

Try $http methods or use $resource directive to make REST calls.

Comment: Thru function call in your controller.

Comment: Ex: $scope. getData = function(){ $http.get()}

Comment: i tried but i didn't get any result it asks for the user authentication details when i type only the url in rest client.

Comment: Enable CORS in server side to access all routes.